# Python - Remove empty bool <class 'str'> element in list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to remove empty elements in a list:

when I print their type

```
x = ['((args[0] AND args[1]) OR args[2])', 'OR', ' ((not args[1]) AND (not args[3]) AND args[2])', '']

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    print("i: "+str(i)+str(x[i])+str(type(x[i]))+str(len(x[i])))
```

I get this:

```
>i: 0((args[0] AND args[1]) OR args[2])<class 'str'>34
>i: 1OR<class 'str'>2
>i: 2 ((not args[1]) AND (not args[3]) AND args[2])<class 'str'>46
>i: 3<class 'str'>0
```

But when I try to remove them like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    print("i: "+str(i)+str(x[i])+str(type(x[i]))+str(len(x[i])))
    if len(x[i] == 0):
        x.remove(x[i])
```

I get an error:

```
 line 5, in <module>
    if len(x[i] == 0):
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Why can I print their length `len()` it works, but when I try to compare it: `if(len(x[i])` I get an error ?

And how can I properly remove them ?

Comment: What do you expect to be the length of `x[i] == 0`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be True ?
If I do:
x = ''
len(x) == 0
> True

Comment: Yes. And `len(x == 0)` = `len(False)` = ???

Comment: Yeah but when I try to filter it out as 'False' doen't work, I tried this:
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    if x[i] != False:
        print("i: "+str(i)+"     "+x[i])

Comment: Ok, I see my mistake now, Thang M. Pham explained it to me below. Thanks for your answer, it's clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for removing empty elements properly

```
x = [i for i in x if i != '']
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['((args[0] AND args[1]) OR args[2])', 'OR', ' ((not args[1]) AND (not args[3]) AND args[2])']
```

Comment: Regarding your question, it should be `if len(x[i]) == 0:` instead of `if len(x[i] == 0):` so here is your mistake.